# Response from multiple transaction participant jpos

Tags: java, jpos

I have a transaction manager which i configured like this

```
<txnmgr name="txnmgr" logger="Q2" class="org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager">
    <property name="space" value="tspace:mySpace"/>
    <property name="queue" value="TransactionQueue"/>
    <property name="max-sessions" value="10"/>

    <participant class="main.java.com.transaction.manager.Switch" logger="Q2">
      <property name="0800" value="NetworkManagement" />
      <property name="0200" value="FinancialTransaction" />
    </participant>

    <participant class="main.java.com.transaction.manager.FinancialTransactionResponse" logger="Q2"/>

    <group name="NetworkManagement">
      <participant class="main.java.com.transaction.manager.NetworkManagementResponse" logger="Q2" />
    </group>

    <group name="FinancialTransaction">
      <participant class="main.java.com.transaction.manager.FinancialTransactionValidateMessage" logger="Q2" />
      <participant class="main.java.com.transaction.manager.FinancialTransactionQueryRemoteHost1" logger="Q2" />


<participant class="main.java.com.transaction.manager.FinancialTransactionQueryRemoteHost2" logger="Q2" />

    </group>

</txnmgr>
```

in my FinancialTransactionQueryRemoteHost1 i have

```
@Override
    public int prepare(long l, Serializable srlzbl) {
        try{

            channelManager =  ((ChannelManager) NameRegistrar.get("jpos-host1-adaptor"));
            ISOMsg reqMsg = (ISOMsg) ((Context) srlzbl).get(Constants.REQUEST_KEY);
            ISOMsg respMsg = channelManager.sendMsg(reqMsg);
            ((Context) srlzbl).put(Constants.RESPONSE_KEY, respMsg);
            return PREPARED;

        }catch(NameRegistrar.NotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ABORTED;
        }catch(Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
            return ABORTED;
        }

    }
```

in my FinancialTransactionQueryRemoteHost2 i have

```
    @Override
        public int prepare(long l, Serializable srlzbl) {
            try{

                channelManager =  ((ChannelManager) NameRegistrar.get("jpos-host2-adaptor"));
                ISOMsg reqMsg = (ISOMsg) ((Context) srlzbl).get(Constants.REQUEST_KEY);
                ISOMsg respMsg = channelManager.sendMsg(reqMsg);
                ((Context) srlzbl).put(Constants.RESPONSE_KEY, respMsg);
                return PREPARED;

            }catch(NameRegistrar.NotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return ABORTED;
            }catch(Throwable t){
                t.printStackTrace();
                return ABORTED;
            }

        }
```

in my Financialtransactionresponse i have

```
@Override
  public int prepare(long id, Serializable context) {
    Context ctx = (Context)context;
        ISOMsg respMsg = (ISOMsg)ctx.get(Constants.RESPONSE_KEY);
 //Get IsoMsg from host1
 //Get IsoMsg from host2
 //compare field 39 response if both are 00 
        String bit39 = respMsg.getString(70);
        if(bit39==null){
            respMsg.set(39,"06");
        }
        ctx.put(Constants.RESPONSE_KEY,respMsg);
        return PREPARED;
  }
```

in my transactionresponse how do i get the response of the 2 participant so i can compare before responding i.e comment above on how i would like it to be achieved

Answer (score 2):

You only need to put the responses under two different keys. Let's say response1 and response2:

In `FinancialTransactionQueryRemoteHost1.prepare`:

```
((Context) srlzbl).put("response1", respMsg);
```

In `FinancialTransactionQueryRemoteHost2.prepare`:

```
((Context) srlzbl).put(Constants.RESPONSE_KEY, respMsg);
```

Then in `Financialtransactionresponse.prepare`

```
ISOMsg resp1 = ctx.get("response1"), resp2 = ctx.get("response2");
```

You can use whatever strings you want and define contants for them. You can reuse de `CONTEXT_KEY` for the first and another key for the second.

Also and perhaps better yet, you can merge the replies in your `FinancialTransactionQueryRemoteHost2` participant.

FYI participants are ran sequentially.

And even more you could reuse the standard QueryHost participant see [this tutorial](http://jpos.org/doc/tutorials/jpos-gateway.pdf)

Thanks to [Murtuza Chhil response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jpos-users/kqFqkofvBRU/3uSHXs5HAgAJ) to [ISOMsg parallel request to multiple MUX](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jpos-users/kqFqkofvBRU/discussion) jpos thread you can also use the join participant as described in [Parallel Processing](http://jpos.org/blog/2007/01/parallel-processing/) to make the two queries in parallel.