# ISOMsg request to multiple MUX in parallel

Tags: java, jpos

i have a situation where i have to send an ISOMsg request to two channels in parallel get the result from both channels and compare some fields from both results before responding to the client that sent the request, please how do i go about this. below is what i have done

```
 @Override
  public boolean process ( ISOSource isoSrc, ISOMsg isoMsg ) { 

      try{
        if(isoMsg.getMTI() .equals("0200")){

            MUX mux = (MUX) NameRegistrar.getIfExists("mux.jpos-host1-mux");

            ISOMsg reply = mux.request(isoMsg, 10 * 1000);

            if(reply != null){
                System.out.println(new String(reply.pack()));

                if(reply.getValue(39).equals("00")){
                    MUX mux_bank = (MUX) NameRegistrar.getIfExists("mux.jpos-host2-mux");
                    ISOMsg reply_bank = mux_bank.request(isoMsg, 10 * 1000);
                    if (isoMsg.hasField(39)) {
                            if(reply_bank.getValue(39).equals("00")){
                                reply.set(39, "00");
                                isoSrc.send(reply_bank);

                            }
                      }else{
                        //send a reversal to host1
                    }
                }else{
                    isoSrc.send(reply);
                }
            }
        }

      }catch(ISOException e){

      } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(ISO_HAWK.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      return false;
  }
```

is this a correct way to go about this (i.e considering the response time will be bigger, because i have to get a response from host1 before sending the request to host2 etc. or is there a better way to achieve this (in parallel) and how do i go about it.

Comment: you could parallelize using threads or the asynchronous call to mux and await the finalization of both, you could do that using java concurrency. I could provide an example somewhere in the future as a response, but the recomended way is using participants as in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/48407977/3444205.